# Better way to code rather than using whole new code with `insertAdjacentHTML`

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add new input and button when clicking certain button.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label>...</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 input-group" id="aa">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" id="bbb" name="bbb" required type="text">
        <div class="input-group-append">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info float-right" onclick="add()">Add</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is my question.

1. By clicking on button, I want to add same input and button under input(id="aa"). And every time when clicking on new button I want to add new input and button again.

   - I tried to solve by using `insertAdjacentHTML`. But this requires long whole new code. So wondering if there is more simple way to add new input and button.

   ※ Code I am trying to add

   `<div class="col-sm-9 input-group" id="aa">
      <input class="form-control mr-2" id="bbb" name="bbb" required type="text">
      <div class="input-group-append">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info float-right" onclick="add()">Add</button>
       </div>
   </div>`
2. Next I am trying to change adding button to delete button when new input and button is clicked. Can use remove method. But I need each `id` of new input  and button. So wondering if there is specific way to assign different `id` to new input and button every time I add one?

Hope someone can show me at least where I can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the ID, use relative addressing, parentNode, closest etc. And use cloneNode to get the stuff you want to duplicate

Note, you do need "new long code" for this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.addEventListener("click",function(e) { // delegation
    var elem = e.target;
    if (elem.className.indexOf("btn") == 0) {
      var div = elem.closest("div.form-group");
      if (elem.innerText=="Add") {
        var newDiv = div.cloneNode(true);  // deep cloning
        newDiv.querySelector(".btn").innerText="Del";
        // here you may want to rename the input field too
        div.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
      }
      else {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label>...</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" name="bbb" required type="text">
        <div class="input-group-append">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info float-right">Add</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. Thanks! This helped me alot!